# Validate Email with regular expression where the number of extensions in the domain part can vary

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I need a regular expression to match a pattern like this. I have tried using this -

```
if(str.match(/^([a-zA-Z-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z]{1,5})\.([a-zA-Z]{1,5})(\.[a-zA-Z]{1,5})?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$/)){
  console.log("the email is valid");
}
```

But this counts *user@aaa.bb.cccc* as valid whereas it should **not be**.

The full requirements of the email to be valid -

1. The username part of the email can have only words(case insensitive), dots(.) and dashes(-). Length
   of 1 or more characters.
2. The domain name part can have 2 to 4 extensions. For example, username@ext.ext.ext.ext this
   email has 4 extensions.
3. All the extensions can only have words(case insensitive), and the length can of 1 to 5 characters
   long except the last extension. The last extension can only be of 2 to 3 characters long. For
   Example,

   *user@aaa.bb.cccc.dd* **is valid**

   *user@aaa.bv.cccc* **is not valid**

   *I am having trouble with solving this part. As the extension count can vary I don't know How to check if only the last part of the email has 2
   to 3 characters?*

I know this type of question might be answered before. I am new to Regular Expressions and I could not find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match a single `[a-zA-Z]{1,5}` after the @.

Then match 0 to 2 times `\.[a-zA-Z]{1,5}` and match `\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}` at the end to match 2-4 parts in total.

```
^[a-zA-Z.-]+@[a-zA-Z]{1,5}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{1,5}){0,2}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xCqOjp/1)

If you want to match "words", you might also use `\w` instead of using `[a-zA-Z]` to also match digits and `_`

```js
const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z.-]+@[a-zA-Z]{1,5}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{1,5}){1,2}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
[
  "user@aaa.bb.cccc.dd",
  "user@aaa.bb.cccc.dd.ee",
  "user@aaa.bv.cccc"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(`the email is ${pattern.test(s) ? "" : "not "}valid for ${s}`)
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my issue. One thing though, the regex is not matching *user@aaaa.bbb* 
I think at least one pattern is needed to match the capturing group. I got around it with this 
    /^[a-zA-Z.-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,5}\.){1,3}[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/
Is this okay to use?

Comment: @ShamsadAnam I made a counting mistake, try it with the quantifier starting at 0 like `^[a-zA-Z.-]+@[a-zA-Z]{1,5}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{1,5}){0,2}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$`  https://regex101.com/r/xCqOjp/1 Updated the answer.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks to you, I got introduced with the power of capturing groups.

Comment: The `(?:` notation is a non capturing group which can be repeated 0, 1 or 2 times using the quantifier `{0,2}`